# rails 4 Ruby Search on local attribute and foreign attribute keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I am trying to have a keywords search field that can search on multiple attributes.

here is my search_requests method, i have it working but it does not work for ALL attributes it only works when i comment one line of code out.

I know it is an issue to do with the :join. But i am not sure how to include normal attributes (non forigen table, local) in that same line of code.

Any advice would be great.

Please could someone inform me how to write this line of code in the correct way.

---

```
requests = requests.joins(:house).where(["houses.doorno LIKE ? OR 
houses.house_title LIKE ? title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%# 
{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]).where(["title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", 
 "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%"]) if keywords.present?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using where clause in associated table use "includes" and you can create query like below. But check properly your table name singular/plural.

```
 requests = requests.includes(:houses).references(:houses).where("houses.doorno LIKE ? OR 
 houses.house_title LIKE ?", "%# 
{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%").where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", 
 "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
```

Comment: Thank you but i get error wrong number of bind variables (2 for 4) still

Comment: Yes, because you were putting more columns name but not giving values to each on first where clause, but now I have updated that.